# how to mirror a samba folder into an ext4 folder via rsync?

Tags: rsync, backup

I have a FreeBSD file server and I also have just setup a xUbuntu 15.10 desktop.

The desktop was previously running OS X but I backed up my files to the FreeBSD server before installing xUbuntu. After install xUbuntu, I erased the partitions on the HFS+ disk via fdisk.

I just copied back my files from the server to a local disk. But I'm experiencing weird behavior from rsync.

**steps I used:**

```
1st step: rsync -aiv --delete --progress --dry-run /server/my-stuff/ /localdisk/my-stuff/
```

This list all the stuff missing in the destination drive. Obviously, my localdisk is empty since I just moved to Linux.

```
2nd step: rsync -aiv --delete --progress /server/my-stuff/ /localdisk/my-stuff/
```

This then copied all my files to /localdisk/my-stuff/. As a test, I tried running the 1st step again:

```
3rd step: rsync -aiv --delete --progress --dry-run /server/my-stuff/ /localdisk/my-stuff/
```

I was expecting 0 files to be shown but it seems rsync wants to copy all the files again. I'm saying "all" just because the number of files it wants to copy is too many to count.

So any ideas on how to fix this? thanks

Comment: You still have --dry-run in the second command.

Comment: thanks for the comment. copy/paste mistake. I didn't have --dry-run when I ran the rsync command the 2nd time.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, Samba shares may adhere to the same [constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724290.aspx) as a FAT volume, that is: the timestamps have a minimum resolution of 2 seconds. `rsync` doesn't know that and assumes that the file is "new" and transfers it again. Try using the `--modify-window=2` [option](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html) to get around that behaviour:

```
rsync -aiv --delete --progress --dry-run --modify-window=2 /server/my-stuff/ /localdisk/my-stuff/
```